# How to disable click event for SubMenu in Ant Design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to prevent the [`SubMenu`](https://ant.design/components/menu/) from opening and closing its child menu items when you click on it. Is there a way to do this without setting it to `disabled`? (Which affects how the button looks) I essentially want the SubMenu to look the same, without toggling functionality of its children.

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep a `SubMenu` open all the time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve the desired behavior, you need to use combination of `openKeys` and `onOpenChange` [properties of `Menu`](https://ant.design/components/menu/#Menu) like so:

```js
const OPEN_KEYS = ['sub1'];

export default function App() {
  const [openKeys, setOpenKeys] = useState(OPEN_KEYS);
  const onOpenChange = openKeys => setOpenKeys([...OPEN_KEYS, ...openKeys]);
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <Menu
        openKeys={openKeys}
        onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
      >
        ...
      </Menu>
    </FlexBox>
  );
}
```

In the above example, `OPEN_KEYS` will always stay open and won't affect its `Menu.Item` / `Menu.ItemGroup` children.

[image: Edit Q-57360265-SubMenuAlwaysOpen]

Comment: I suppose I should've made my question more clear. I used something similar to your question to keep all my menus open by default, however, what I wanted to do is to prevent being able to close those menus (by preventing the click event on the SubMenu). Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Check the sandbox, you can't close the submenu - 'sub1', on the other hand, all others are acting normal.

Comment: Wow that code works like magic. It's more better than my approach where I tried to edit the css of the disabled item directly. I never managed to finish it as I had struggled to find the css to restore the text color.